# Compojure with configurable base route

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure

I am working with Clojure, Ring and Compojure for some time now, but I am still fairly new.

What I need to know is how to make a configurable base route, for example:

```
/:base-route

/:base-route/user

/:base-route/settings
```

*/:base-route* can be different (api, company, stuff...) and will depend on an internal check. What I can't do is create a universal check for all routes to see if */:base-route* has the appropriate value. For example */:base-route* is configured to be **/api**, but the user tries **/company/user** -> the response must be 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the way to do it is with a regular expression and a context:

```
(defroutes routes
  (context ["/:base-route" :base-route (re-pattern base-route)] [base-route]
             (GET  "/user" [] (str "base: " base-route " user"))
             (GET  "/settings" [] (str "base: " base-route " settings"))))
```

Comment: I know that but I forgot. I did not wait impatiently 24 hours, refreshing StackOverflow...

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion.

Comment: It's not against you, it's against the fact that I need to wait 24 hours in order to do something that I can undo after that anyway.